# Is it possible to execute a javascript in a new window with window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, window.location

I am trying to open a new window and execute a javascript code on the new page.

I'm not really sure why it doesn't execute the code - maybe it's not possible like this - anyway, the new window opens but the javascript doesn't get executed.

Here is my code:

var nstart = window.open("http://examplepage.html");

```
function loginnow(){
var htmlstring = "javascript: var zTextFields = window.document.getElementsByTagName(\"input\"); for (var i=0; i < zTextFields.length; i++) {thefield=zTextFields[i].name; if (!thefield) thefield=zTextFields[i].id; if (thefield == \"login\") zTextFields[i].value=\"_ext_cancom\"; if (thefield == \"password\")zTextFields[i].value=\"canfinag?!\";} window.document.getElementById(\"sign-in\").click();";

nstart.location.href = htmlstring;
}

nstart.addEventListener('load', loginnow, true);
```

Is it even possible to execute code like this? Please help ^-^
I'm also using '\' as an escape character so I can use " in the string ->  \"

When I replace the \" with " and directly inject it into the page the script works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add the javascript you want to execute in the new new page, and then make it run [when document ready](http://makeagreatsite.com/javascript/how-execute-javascript-when-document-ready). So you will can just open the new page, JS will run automatically

Comment: i'm not able to change the page - it's a webpage from a local service running on the server pc

Answer (score 0):

If the new window is on the same domain you can access the contents by doing something like this.

```
var nstart = window.open("http://examplepage.html");

function loginnow() {
  var zTextFields = nstart.document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
  for (var i=0; i < zTextFields.length; i++) {
    thefield=zTextFields[i].name;
    if (!thefield) 
      thefield=zTextFields[i].id; 
    if (thefield == "login") 
      zTextFields[i].value="_ext_cancom"; 
    if (thefield == "password")
      zTextFields[i].value="canfinag?!";
  } 
  nstart.document.getElementById("sign-in").click();
}

nstart.addEventListener('load', loginnow, true);
```

You shouldn't really try to inject code onto the new window but you can access the dom and run javascript from the parent window.

Comment: hmmmm - this looks good to me - but for some reason the function doesn't get executed (both parent and child page)...my brain starts melting... ^^

Comment: hmm try changing the listener to the document.

nstart.document.addEventListener('load', loginnow, true);

Comment: ah unfortunately it looks like that event never fires with popups.

You'll probably have to have something that polls the readystate of the document.